# Add a missing address to Google Maps?

Tags: google, address

My address is not on Google Maps.

If I search Google Maps for my address it does not recognize it.

How can I add my missing address to Google Maps?

Answer (score 4):

When logged in to Google you can "Add a missing place" from the sidebar:

[image]

Where you can add in the address details:

[image]